# Monotonicity of a sequence $\frac{(\mu/2)^n}{n!}K_{n-\frac{1}{2}}(\mu)$

Tags: bessel-functions, monotone-functions

I want to investigate the monotonicity of the sequence $\{p_n\}$ given by
\begin{equation}
p_n=\frac{(\mu/2)^n}{n!}K_{n-\frac{1}{2}}(\mu),
\end{equation}
where $0<\mu<2$ and $K_\nu(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. I did some simulation, it is monotone decreasing with respect to $n$, but so far have no idea how to prove it. Can you please help a bit? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mu>$ and $\nu>0$, we know that $K_\nu(\mu)>0$. We consider the ratio
\begin{equation}
 \frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}=\frac{\mu}{2n}\frac{K_{n-\tfrac{1}{2}}(\mu)}{K_{n-\tfrac{3}{2}}(\mu)}
\end{equation} 
In theorem 1.2 of [this paper](http://emis.u-strasbg.fr/journals/HOA/JIA/Volume2010/253035.pdf), the following inequality is derived
\begin{equation}
 \frac{K_{\nu}(t)}{K_{\nu-1}(t)}<\frac{\nu+\sqrt{\nu^2+t^2}}{t}
\end{equation} 
for real $\nu$. Then
\begin{equation}
 \frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}<\frac{n-\tfrac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\left( n-\tfrac{1}{2} \right)^2+\mu^2}}{2n}
\end{equation} 
It can be shown that, for $n>\mu^2+\tfrac{1}{4}$, rhs of the previous expression is an increasing function of $n$ bounded by 1 for $n\to \infty$. Thus $p_{n+1}<p_n$.

It can further be shown that rhs is lower than 1 for $n>\frac{\mu^2}{2}$. If $ \mu<2$ then the sequence decreases for $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. For the last expression, should the denominator be $2n$ instead of $2n-1$?

Comment: You are right. I corrected the typo.

Comment: Then use this bound, we can only prove for $n>\mu^2+\frac{1}{4}$, but not for all $n\ge0$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but a more detailed analysis of the function shows that it is true for $n> \mu^2/2$ (which is the solution of rhs=1).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am curious about is there any other inequalities for $\frac{K_\nu(t)}{K_{\nu-1}(t)}$?

Comment: Some references to inequalities can be found at [NIST](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.37)